# How to find the date range of the past week? Sunday to Saturday but should not exceed the month it belongs to

Tags: c#, .net

I need an algorithm to get the past week dates from  **sunday - saturday.**

The application will run **every monday.**

Examples: Date Today is September 1, 2014 (Monday) 
**Result should be:** August 24 (Sunday) - August 30 (Saturday) 
But since August 31 is the last day for August, this should be included. 

Another Example: October 6, 2014 (Monday) 
**Result Should be:** Oct 1 (wed) - 4 (sat)

So basically, it should consider that the output should be the range of the month it belongs to. We must not let months cross each other. I'll really appreciate all the help i can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one should be what your are looking for:

```
public static class Week
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> UpTo(DateTime upTo)
    {
        var lastMonday = upTo.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
            ? upTo.AddDays(-6)
            : upTo.AddDays(-(int) upTo.DayOfWeek + 1);
        var lastSunday = lastMonday.AddDays(-1);
        var sundayBefore = lastSunday.AddDays(-7);

        var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(lastSunday.Year, lastSunday.Month, 1);
        var startDay = firstDayOfMonth >= sundayBefore ? firstDayOfMonth : sundayBefore;

        for (var day = startDay; day < lastSunday; day = day.AddDays(1))
            yield return day;
    }
}
```

I think the code is rather self-explaining - maybe the only thing not so clear is the line where I calculate `lastMonday` - for this you have to know that the `DayOfWeek` is a enumeration where `Monday` is `1` - so I get a number representing the day of week and subtract day accordingly.
Sadly there is an edge case I missed first: `Sunday` is 0 so this would get the *next* monday if you start on a sunday - this is why the additional check is in there - just in case you cannot guarantee the *give a monday* rule.

Here are two Xunit test-cases that check your criterias:

```
[Fact]
public void SepTest()
{
    var sunday = new DateTime(2014, 8, 24);
    var expected = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(d => sunday.AddDays(d));

    var week = Week.UpTo(new DateTime(2014, 9, 1));
    Assert.Equal(expected, week);
}

[Fact]
public void OctTest()
{
    var wednesday = new DateTime(2014, 10, 1);
    var expected = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(d => wednesday.AddDays(d));

    var week = Week.UpTo(new DateTime(2014, 10, 6));
    Assert.Equal(expected, week);
}

[Fact]
public void Day_EdgeCase()
{
    var sunday = new DateTime(2014, 8, 24);
    var expected = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(d => sunday.AddDays(d));

    var week = Week.UpTo(new DateTime(2014, 9, 7));
    Assert.Equal(expected, week);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what should i pass as "upTo"? is it the DateTime.Today? What I also need is the Start Date and End Date of the range only. Not the whole range. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you pass in your "monday" (or any other day / time) - the algorithm will yield all days of the week before the week your day is a part of (just like you wanted) - have a look at the Tests at the end of the answer for example ussages

Comment: If you need the some kind of string and I misinterpreted your answer you can just take the first and last day in the enumeration I returned and format as you wish ;)

Comment: GREAT! Works like charm!

Comment: hi can we add a logic wherein if we found out that the last day in the enumeration is near the end of month. Example is august 30, saturday but next to it is august 31, we need to add the august 31 to the range too.

Comment: sure *you* can - first of course you have to think about what **near** means here - than you just write another function that checks the last day and adds another if neccessary

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have written may be not so good but might be helpful for you.

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    //currentDate = DateTime.Parse("9/8/2014");       //Just for test.

    List<PastWeekDays> list = new List<PastWeekDays>();
    //Started loop from 2 beacause it will pick current datetime every monday,so 2 days ago will be saturday.
    for (int i =2; i < 9; i++)
    {
        DateTime lastDate = currentDate.AddDays(-double.Parse((i).ToString()));
        if (lastDate.Month != currentDate.Month)
            break;
        PastWeekDays day = new PastWeekDays();
        day.Date = lastDate.Day.ToString();
        day.DayName = lastDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        list.Add(day);
    }

//This is custom class you may not need it.
public class PastWeekDays
{
public string Date { get; set; }
public string DayName { get; set; }
}
```